# Proof that if $d,d'$ are gcd($f,g$) where $f,g$ are polynomials, then $d = cd'$ for some polynomial $c$

Tags: number-theory

Here is my current thought; Let $f = df', g = dg'$ for some polynomials $f',g'$

by division theorem

$f = gq + r$ for some polynomial $r,q$. We have $r = f - gq = df' - dg'q = d(f'-dg')$; hence, $d$ divides $r$; similarly, $d'$ divides $r$.

So theree are polynomial $a,b$ such that $r = da = d'b$.

My plan is to show that $r=gcd(f,g)$ as well, so I have degree($r$) = degree($da$) = degree($d'b$) = degree($d$) = degree($d'$) implies that $a,b$ just constant.  I  can write $d = \frac{b}{a}d'$

But I'm stuck at how to prove $r=gcd(f,g)$ Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from the definition of a greatest common divisor, which is that it is a common divisor, and every common divisor divides it. Thus as $d'(x)$ is a common divisor, and $d(x)$ is a greatest common divisor, $d'(x)|d(x)$, which is equivalent to saying that there exists a $c(x)$ such that $d'(x)c(x) = d(x)$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to FAQs.

Comment: It's not a dupe answer. This is the simplest way of proving this statement.

Comment: It is a dupe ansewr of that linked (and *many* others). Please search before answersing to avoid such.